# how to clear the textarea in onpaste method?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onPasteMe(pObj) 
{     
// validate  pasted text     
var input  = window.clipboardData.getData('Text'); 
document.getElementById("txt1").value = input ;
var m= stripCharacters(input,pObj) ;
    if(m)
    {
 input=input.replace(/[\s]/g,'\r'); 
 var n=input.split(/\r/g).length; 
 alert(n);
    }
  }

function stripCharacters(input,pObj) {
var r = new RegExp("[^\\s\\r\\t\\n0-9]", "g");
var find = input.match(r) ;      
if(find)
   {   
 alert('String contains both alpha-numeric or your pre-defined special characters!');  
 pObj.innerHTML = ""; 
 return false; 
   }
 return true; 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea cols=19 id = "txt1" onPaste="onPasteMe(this);"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

if i paste numbers in the text area like 1233445 the pasted value should present in the text area, but if i pasted values like assdfsdf 123243' or 2313adsdad the text area should get clear automatically???

```
i used below codes but its not worked for me please help,
pObj.innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("txt1").value ="";
```

Comment: So you want to just allow numbers? What are you trying to do?

Comment: yes am allowing only number, not other character..

Comment: what was the reason for devote? am using only IE browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onPasteMe(pObj) 
{     
// validate  pasted text     
var input  = window.clipboardData.getData('Text'); 
document.getElementById("txt1").value = input ;
var m= stripCharacters(input,pObj) ;
    if(m)
    {
 input=input.replace(/[\s]/g,'\r'); 
 var n=input.split(/\r/g).length; 
 alert(n);
    }
    return false;
  }

function stripCharacters(input,pObj) {
var r = new RegExp("[^\\s\\r\\t\\n0-9]", "g");
var find = input.match(r) ;      
if(find)
   {   
 alert('String contains both alpha-numeric or your pre-defined special characters!');  
 pObj.value = ""; 
 return false; 
   }
 return true; 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea cols=19 id = "txt1" onPaste="return onPasteMe(this);"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

1. you should use pObj.value="" to empty the textarea.
2. you need return false for onPaste() function.

Answer (score -1):

First, onPaste isn't fully supported
Reference: [JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser)

Comment: what was the reason for devote? am using only IE browser. for me onpaste method is working fine only.

Comment: @jcrshankar I didn't do it but my upvote will even it out :). Some negative nancy is downvoting like crazy in here.

Comment: dear Jared, can u please explain me.. the reason for failure??

Comment: oh thanks Jared, i will receive the value through window.clipboarddata.getdat('Test') is there is any other alternative way?

Comment: @jcrshankar If you're only worried about ie... you can ignore the other error... still working

Comment: @jcrshankar I got it add return false; after the if(m) statement

Comment: Please try to ensure that your answers can stand on their own, even if a link breaks. Is there something from the external link you could cite _within_ your answer?